# Is there a more efficient way to load SQL results, or join tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm sort of creating a social media site, and i'm trying to find the most efficient/least time-consuming way to load all the most recent posts of all the people that you "subscribe" to. I think the way I did it was kind of low-tech, and would probably take a while if you follow a certain objective "many" number of followers. I tried to make it quicker by saving the initial list of followers that I got from an SQL result to a session so it wouldn't have to reload again, unless someone blocked you or you unfollowed someone.

Below $que_posts[6] loads all the people you're following, and for each of them I have a respective UNION clause that joins it to the SQL query.

Please don't post about how i'm using the procedural style, I had the character encoding and appropriate character filters set.

The schema/table of sg_permissions and posts

```
|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|access_type|varchar(30)|No|
|towhom|varchar(30)|No|
|date_g|date|No|
|granted_by|varchar(35)|No|
|//**sgp_id**//|int(11)|No|

== Dumping data for table sg_permissions

|friend snowglobe|nolvorite|2014-12-16|nerd|1
|friend snowglobe|nerd|2014-12-17|nolvorite|2
```

posts

```
===Database captiv8

== Table structure for table posts

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|content|varchar(15000)|Yes|NULL
|cnttype|int(11)|No|
|msgtype|char(20)|Yes|NULL
|forwhom|text|No|
|parent|int(11)|No|
|//**postid**//|int(11)|No|
|stamptime|timestamp|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
|bywhom|text|No|
|title|varchar(150)|Yes|NULL
|thread_nick|varchar(50)|Yes|NULL
|topic_hash|varchar(10)|Yes|NULL
|settings|int(11)|No|1
|thread_id|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|level|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|upvotes|int(11)|No|1
|downvotes|int(11)|No|0
|post_type|int(11)|No|0
== Dumping data for table posts

|Reply to this comment... Ergo, comment on this comment.|2|NULL|n-a|28|35|2014-11-28 15:19:01|nolvorite|Comments|Comments|acf8ac4cf4|1|19|NULL|1|0|0
|another one|2|NULL|n-a|33|36|2014-11-29 18:51:41|nolvorite|Comments|Comments|383780840c|1|19|NULL|1|0|0
|last comment generation to boot?|2|NULL|n-a|36|37|2014-11-29 22:50:18|nolvorite|Comments|Comments|1974971f18|1|19|NULL|1|0|0
|test last comment generation?|2|NULL|n-a|36|38|2014-11-29 22:51:19|nolvorite|Comments|Comments|0aadae2602|1|19|NULL|1|0|0
|test once and never again|2|NULL|n-a|36|39|2014-11-30 02:33:37|nolvorite|Comments|Comments|6a334ce691|1|19|NULL|1|0|0
```

actual code

```
$zoom = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE bywhom='$logged_dt[username]' AND cnttype=1";
//have to find an efficient way to load the most recent posts
//among other ways of assortment
//i'm gonna have to put it in a session
//clear it when the person follows new people/the person gets blocked
//that way it's only going to have to search once as long as those things don't happen
if(!isset($_SESSION['content_pool'])){
$que_posts[6] = mysqli_query($db_main, "SELECT * FROM sg_permissions WHERE towhom='$_MONITORED[login_q]'");
$xn = 0;
while($que_others_posts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($que_posts[6])){ $xn++;
//sort em'
$_SESSION['content_pool'][preg_replace("#[ :]+#","",$que_others_posts['access_type'])] = array($xn => $que_others_posts);
}
}
for($i = 1;$i <= count($_SESSION['content_pool']);$i++){
foreach($_SESSION['content_pool']['friendsnowglobe'] as $friends_feed){
$zoom .= " UNION SELECT * FROM posts WHERE bywhom='".$friends_feed['granted_by']."' AND cnttype=1"; //I have a feeling this is horribly inefficient
} }
var_dump($_SESSION['content_pool']);
$que_posts[0] = mysqli_query($db_main, $zoom . " ORDER by stamptime DESC LIMIT 0,75");
while($que_own = mysqli_fetch_assoc($que_posts[0])){
//begin posts
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you supplied your schema in addition to what you wish to extract from this schema.

Comment: Oh. Right my bad, I'll supply it in a second.

Comment: This is kind of embarrassing, I guess, but I haven't really implemented any changes to the schema in my database. I am looking to get all values from sg_permissions where the permission's granted to the user currently logged in and the type of access granted to it the fastest way possible.

Comment: I haven't really made a schema for this... I mean. Eugh. I wasn't familiar with the concept until today.

Comment: I am not sure how you were able to write the code you provided without knowing what a schema is. The schema I am requesting from you is the names of your database tables and what the fields are in each of those tables. You obviously have a schema, maybe you did not originally create it, but the fact that you are querying for posts and permissions implies that you do have a schema.

Comment: OH that. I thought you were talking about the settings in a schema. I guess I always knew what a schema is, although I wasn't familiar with the terminology. Okay I got it

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN sg_permissions ON posts.bywhom = sg_permissions.granted_by WHERE sg_permissions.access_type = 'friendsnowglobe' AND sg_permissions.towhom = '$logged_dt[username]'

Comment: Let me see if i'm getting the query's abstractions: You'll be joining each post data where sg_permissions' granted_by and posts' bywhom has the same value, and said sg_permissions' rows have a set access_type and a set towhom? I assume this entire SQL statement could be appended to the first query staring at "INNER JOIN"? Thanks a ton by the way.

Comment: For each post, retrieve all friends of the author and match that the logged in user is one of those friends. After examining this query, it would be better if you moved the sg_permissions.towhom = '$logged_dt[username]' condition to the join clause.

Comment: SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN sg_permissions ON posts.bywhom = sg_permissions.granted_by  AND sg_permissions.towhom = '$logged_dt[username]' WHERE sg_permissions.access_type = 'friendsnowglobe'

Comment: I'm trying the query on phpmyadmin, but it's not showing up any results. I'm trying to tweak it. You're well on the right track though

Comment: Nevermind I got it. The original value for access_type is 'friend snowglobe' and not 'friendsnowglobe', I just removed the spaces so it could be an array key. Thanks a ton

Comment: I'm sorry to be blowing up your notifications lol, but now I have another problem. I want to be able to display the user's own posts too, but their snowglobe settings are predefined and not under sg_permissions. How would you assume values for columns that don't exist? I tried SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN sg_permissions ON posts.bywhom = sg_permissions.granted_by AND sg_permissions.towhom = 'nolvorite' WHERE sg_permissions.access_type = 'friend snowglobe' UNION SELECT * FROM posts WHERE bywhom='nolvorite'; but it says it doesn't have the same number of columns.

Comment: Perhaps you should just consider adding a row for every user in sg_permissions where they are their own snowglobe friend.

Comment: I guess that could work. I want to pick your brain though :P

Comment: I would recommend that over making this query even more complicated.

Comment: I always love a good challenge.